# roboearth ar marker template for recording larger objects

Tags: roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I've had good luck using the roboearth re_object_recorder package to record Kinect point cloud models for small objects.  However, now I need to record models of moderately bigger objects (e.g. watering cans) that are too big for the provided AR marker template as they occlude for of the markers.

It looks like there are some parameters (Marker Size, Marker Spacing) in the re_object that should allow for easy customization of the AR marker template for recording of larger markers.  Has anyone done this already, or can you provide guidance about these parameters?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47721/roboearth-ar-marker-template-for-recording-larger-objects/) by [wmcmahan](https://answers.ros.org/users/37/wmcmahan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2012-11-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are 2 ROS parameters you might want to adjust:

- /marker_spacing is the distance (in m) between the center points of 2 adjacent markers.
- /marker_size is the side length (in mm) of one marker.

As a first trial, I would try to scale up the whole marker pattern to a size meeting your requirements and then adjust these parameters.

---

Originally posted by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) with karma: 916 on 2012-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wmcmahan](https://answers.ros.org/users/37/wmcmahan/) on 2012-11-13**:
Thanks for the explanation.  I'll give this a try in the upcoming week or so.

**Comment by [wmcmahan](https://answers.ros.org/users/37/wmcmahan/) on 2012-11-14**:
Looks like it worked.  I just cut out the AR markers from the original template and pasted them on a larger board at even spacings.  Requires resizing the bounding box as well though.